# Netlogo: Convert Gray Code to Binary

Tags: netlogo, gray-code

I am using genetic algorithms to determine survival in my Netlogo model, and the ultimate output of the GA is a decimal number between 0 and 1, inclusive.  For crossover / mutation purposes, I need to work with gray code rather than binary numbers.  I have a function to convert binary to decimal, but not gray code to binary (which I've struggled with).

Any suggestions on how to code a gray code to binary function?

Comment: Yours is not eally a NetLogo question.  But here's a tutorial:
http://www.electrical4u.com/gray-code-binary-to-gray-code-and-that-to-binary-conversion/

Comment: There's not really a formula - you need to set up a segmentation into 4 bit sections, convert each of those (with nested ifelse) and then concatenate the converted sections.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above comments.

I did find another solution:  the "bitstring: extension for Netlogo.  I spoke with the author, and he added a "to-gray" function.

https://github.com/garypolhill/netlogo-bitstring